# Автоскрытие вложенного списка при щелчке на другой вложенный список

Tags: jquery

Есть меню когда при щелчке на элемент списка открывается вложенный список, нужно сделать так что бы при щелчке на другой вложенный список, прошлый вложеный список который мы открыли сам закрывался. Допустим я кликаю на "Первобытные собиратели и охотники", а потом кликаю на "Первобытные земледельцы и скотоводы" и после этого "Первобытные собиратели и охотники" автоматически скрываются. И еще, как сделать что бы список раскрывался при наведении мыши?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#menuCnt > ul > li > a").click(function() {
    $(this).find("~ ul").stop().slideToggle("slov");
  });
});
```

```css
#menuCnt ul li {
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 10px;
  }
  #menuCnt ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#menuCnt > ul > li > ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menuCnt">
 
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="textbold">Первобытные собиратели и охотники</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Древнейшие люди</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Родовые общины охотников и собирателей</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Возникновение искусства и религиозных верований</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="textbold">Первобытные земледельцы и скотоводы</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Возникновение земледелия и скотоводства</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Появление неравенства и знати</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"> Счет лет в истории</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#menuCnt > ul > li > a").click(function() {
    $("#menuCnt > ul > li > ul").stop().slideUp("slow");
    $(this).find("~ ul").stop().slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
#menuCnt ul li {
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 10px;
  }
  #menuCnt ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#menuCnt > ul > li > ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menuCnt">
 
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="textbold">Первобытные собиратели и охотники</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Древнейшие люди</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Родовые общины охотников и собирателей</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Возникновение искусства и религиозных верований</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="textbold">Первобытные земледельцы и скотоводы</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Возникновение земледелия и скотоводства</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Появление неравенства и знати</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"> Счет лет в истории</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

Второе:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#menuCnt > ul > li > *").hover(function() {
    $("#menuCnt > ul > li > ul").stop().slideUp("slow");
    $(this).find("~ ul").stop().slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
#menuCnt ul li {
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 10px;
  }
  #menuCnt ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#menuCnt > ul > li > ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menuCnt">
 
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="textbold">Первобытные собиратели и охотники</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Древнейшие люди</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Родовые общины охотников и собирателей</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Возникновение искусства и религиозных верований</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="textbold">Первобытные земледельцы и скотоводы</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Возникновение земледелия и скотоводства</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Появление неравенства и знати</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"> Счет лет в истории</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Ну у меня будет программа для пк, дипломная работа. Просто нужен еще один сайдбар с наведением. При наведении как то не так работает, навожу на элемент главного списка - отрывается, после навожу на открытый вложеный и он закрывается, как сделать более стабильно работу наведения и что бы когда курсор убирали со списка, все вложенные закрывались? Я знаю что это не сложно сделать, но моих познаний не хватает это сделать(((

Comment: @ПавелРыбакин, дополнил ответ